# Не получается объявить 2 метода в одном классе, в чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: java

Intelij Idea подчеркивает название второго метода. Не могу понять, что не так?

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        int a = 0;
        while (a < 10)
        {

            System.out.println("SSSSSSSSSS");
            a++;

        }

    }


    public void testmetod (String[] s) throws Exception
    {

        int i = 0, k = 0;
        while (i < 10)
        {
            while (k < 9)
            {

                System.out.print("SSSSSSSSS");
                k++;
            }
            System.out.println("S");
            i++;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Наведите мышь на подчёркнутую строку и вам покажут в чём ошибка. Возможно дело в том, что вы не кидаете исключение в методе.

Comment: А какая именно ошибка, нам предлагается угадать самостоятельно? Откомпилируйте и посмотрите.

Comment: `method 'testmethod(java.langString[])' is never used` Чего тут непонятного?

Comment: а почему до него не доходит?

Comment: А почему должно?

Comment: ну мне кажется прошел первый метод, потом дальше читает информацию, нет?

Comment: Вам кажется. Выполняется автоматически при запуске java-программы  только один метод - `main`. А все остальные - только если их вызывают.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При наведении курсора мыши на подчёркнутый элемент всплывает подсказка

```
method 'testmethod(java.langString[])' is never used
```

Это означает, что данный метод нигде не используется. Действительно, ведь данный метод создан, но нигде не вызывается, следовательно, можно обойтись без него, т.е. просто удалить. IntelliJ IDEA и компилятор Java подсказывают таким образом программисту, что он, быть может, забыл где-то вызвать этот метод или же, напротив, забыл его удалить. Но программа тем не менее компилируется и исполняется.

В языке Java в консольном приложении автоматически выполняется только один метод - `static void main(String[])`, все остальные - только если их явно вызывать (экзотику и JavaEE во внимание принимать не будем).